# How can I send more than one value to a key in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to build a diary for travellers with html5 local storage.

The idea is that you fill in a form: Name, picture, date, location.
and at the other page this information will be showed

I'm stuck because I don't know how I can give more value`s to 1 key
and how I can automatically change the key after information from the
form has been saved.

```
<form id="localStorage" method="post" action="">
    <label>Kies foto:</label>
    <br/>
    <input type='file' id="afbeelding" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Onderschrift:</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="Onderschrift" name="Onderschrift" id="Onderschrift" class="Opslaan" required />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="opslaan()" type="button">Verstuur</button>
</form>
```

```
function opslaan() {
    var inputOnderschrift = document.getElementById("Onderschrift");
    localStorage.setItem("onderschrift", inputOnderschrift.value);
}
```

Comment: I hope you mean a diary instead of diarrhea (thats what diarree means in english) :)

Comment: Haha. I had already edited the title which is already peer reviewed :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Local storage is for string key/value pairs. Though you can build a custom object, stringify it and store it, similar to this:

```
var myObject = { name: 'myname', address: 'myaddress' };
localStorage.setItem("myObject", JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Then on the way back use `JSON.parse();` to return it back into an object and re-populate your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an object with the user data (JSON stringified).

For example:

```
var userData = {
  'name': '',
  'picture': '',
  'date': '',
  'location': ''
};

var inputOnderschrift = document.getElementById('Onderschrift');
userData.name = inputOnderschrift.value;

var inputPicture = document.getElementById('Picture');
userData.picture = inputPicture.value;

// etc.

localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
```

In your next page you can retrieve the data like this:

```
var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
var name = userData.name;
var picture = userData.picture;
```

Comment: Instead of `sessionStorage`it should be `localStorage` when you retrieve the data in your second piece of code, right? Please correct this.

Comment: Updated with the userData.picture and JSON stringify/parse

Answer (score 0):

I made an array to put more value`s in 1 key and it worked